# New To Cloud Storage -- Something Went Wrong

Tags: google-cloud-storage, bucket, google-cloud-console

I just created a Google Cloud account and am attempting to load some data from my locale machine to a Storage Bucket for later use in an ML project.  I'm following the quite simple instructions in the tutorial supplied to get a bucket up and running through the console and am having no issue creating a bucket, but when attempting to upload a (any) file I get the error message "Failed to upload a file.  Something went wrong. Try again."

Surely this cannot be so difficult--is there something that I need to do as a new account user to prepare my account before it will let me upload files to the cloud?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

[image: Error displayed in Cloud Console]

Comment: Can you share more? Screenshot? your tutorial? Your command line (if you use CLI)?

Comment: Not too much more to add... the tutorial is the very simple get started one: create a bucket, then upload a file (very complicated steps!).  Not using command line, simply trying to do it through the console.  Not sure how to add a screenshot, sorry, but it's not very helpful in any event, simply a popup that says "Something went wrong. Try again."

Comment: Ok, your bucket exists, your files too. Do you use the drag and drop method or the upload file button?

Comment: Can you please [get a Har file](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204410413-Generating-a-HAR-file-for-troubleshooting) and share it with us while uploading the file? that would be helpfull in order to determine which is the problem. Also can you provide us with more details of your file name? Maybe it contain any special character

Comment: @guillaume have tried both, neither is successful.

Comment: literally encountering this exact issue. It can't be that tough, I am simply trying to add a couple of files. I am trying to really keep any bias (from my experience with AWS) aside while I learn GCP, but so far it has been nothing short of frustrating.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. I create an object, upload a file but then I get the failure message.

Comment: Hello, @fromspace sharing a Har file with us or the log output of running the following command on Cloud Shell ´gsutil -L cp output.txt [OBJECT_LOCATION] gs://[DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]/ I also would advise you to open a new question because the root cause of your issue may be a different one from this question

Comment: Having the exact same problem right now.  I noticed the last three comments above are from the last 24 hours.  Could there be an outage on Google Cloud?

Comment: i think it's a bug still around, never had such issue last year

Comment: The issue went away sometime in the last week because I was able to upload.  It's currently on the screen "Processing text items" ... "This can take several minutes or more. You will be emailed once importing has completed."

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. No idea why it isn't working, but I got it to work fine with the gsutil cli. :)

```
gsutil cp [OBJECT_LOCATION] gs://[DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]/
```

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects

Maybe try that for now until the issue (or whatever this is) is fixed??

Comment: This worked for me too, I wonder if there's a bug with the console for new projects.

Comment: If this issue is observed lately, it may be that the issue is a result of an Internal issue with GCP, which is well documented on this [page](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/zall/20005). The issue is about Google Cloud Identity and Access Management (IAM) causing significantly elevated error rates with several GCP Products including GCS, it seems

Comment: Must be an issue at Google as it was working fine last week and no changes have been made since then from our end.

Answer (score 0):

try another browser. faced this issue when using firefox, tried with chrome and it worked.

Comment: I had tried Chrome on 4/12/2020 and it didn't work.  Now it's 4/19/2020 and on Chrome it seems to be working.